# Mounting a k8s secret using kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I've been searching for a while, but I'm pretty new to kustomize. It's taken me a while to get my head around the concept of overlays etc.

I'm trying to use a kustomization file to mount an existing secret into the pod. I can't do it in the deployment because it's a single deployment with 3 different versions of the deployment being handled by kustomize. Each needs a different secret mounting.

So the obvious answer would be to mount the secret as a volume using either a kustomize file in the base or overlay.

I've found information on generating a secret with kustomize, but the secret already exists and is passed in as a kubernetes secret elsewhere.

So to summarize...

```
base/
├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ statefulset.yaml
├─ service.yaml
├─ instance1/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ instance2/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ instance3/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
```

So I'm looking to handle the mounting of the secret to a volume in the instance locations, because the secret will be different for instance 1,2 & 3.

Is this possible?

TIA

EDIT:

I've added a file for the secret (it's for certs hence being different for each instance).

```
base/
├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ statefulset.yaml
├─ service.yaml
├─ instance1/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
│  ├─ pki.yaml
├─ instance2/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
├─ instance3/
│  ├─ kustomization.yaml
```

My patch file (pki.yaml) looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: de
spec:
  template:
    containers:
    - name: de
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/opt/de/pki"
          name: pki
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: pki
          secret:
            secretName: de_1_pki
```

Then in `./base/instance1/kustomization.yaml` I have:

```
commonLabels:
  app: de-1
resources:
- ../base
nameSuffix: -1
images:
- newName: de-1
  name: de
patches:
  - pki.yaml
```

And for completeness my `./base/kustomization.yaml` file:

```
kind: Kustomization
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
commonLabels:
  app: de
  affinity: directory
resources:
- service.yaml
- statefulset.yaml
```

I'm getting an error when deploying the above. So before I dig too deep, just wondering if I'm barking up the right tree?

Comment: just add this part as a patch of your sts in overlays.

Comment: There are no overlays for the specific instances. The overlay only contains environment specifics. Presumably I can put the patch in the instance directories of base?

Comment: @x4k3p I have edited my question with what I've tried on your advice, am I barking up the right tree?

Comment: Wondering here whether my logic is skewed. Should instance1/2/3 actually be overlays?

Comment: Using overlays seems reasonable. What error do you occur when you try to deploy your current config?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this with lots of tinkering.

I moved the base specifications for instances to overlays, and then added a patch that way.

Thanks